# How can I split a glb model into all parts in React Three Fiber

Tags: reactjs, 3d, gltf, react-three-fiber

I am searching for a way to implement the same functionality as autodesk forge provides to split a 3d model into all available parts and zoom into them. Example is here: https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/database?id=5841e11f540a4d30802763e2

[image: full model]

[image: view of all pieces]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this can be having another model which is the same and has exploding out animation and exploding inward animation, and you can render this model with the outward explosion onClick.

onClick normal view plays inward animation and after render the first model without animation.

Or you can do all these with one model and two animations in it.